# Counting trigger events with oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope

I need to count the trigger events number (how many times synchronization took place). The trigger mode is Normal on negative slope of one of channels (1-st).

Oscilloscope is Lecroy dda-120:

[image]

So it is a pretty old one. However - pretty powerful with a lot of math functionality. But I was not able to find anything to count the events (I've just found how to skip needed events number).

Any help would be appreciate: link to a full datasheet (I don't have one and didn't find any on the web), any information which would help to find needed setting, may be any collateral way...

Comment: I've never seen such a function on regular scopes..

Comment: How frequently do you expect to see the trigger conditions?

Comment: @AliChen I'd use a button to trigger the event and then verify that the number of button push is equal to number of trigger events. As the button and the oscilloscope are in the different rooms I need an extra human or anything to count the trigger events... *So the answer to your question is once in a second or so...*

Comment: @RomanMatveev, ok, this is good. How do you plan to communicate the events back to you? Judging by a floppy on front, it seems unlikely that the instrument has Ethernet interface, right?

Comment: @AliChen, I plan to press the button let's say 10 times and go on foot to the oscilloscope and check if the trigger events equals to 10. There is no Ethernet of course.

Answer (score 3):

The scope should have something like "Trigger Out" BNC connector, on its back. Since the events are rare, the hold-off limits will be non-issue. Take a counter (separate instrument, there are inexpensive models like BK), and count the output pulses. You might need to experiment with configuration of the trigger output, and figure out how to re-arm the scope for next event.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out this link?

http://www.testequipmenthq.com/datasheets/LECROY-DDA120-Datasheet.pdf

This may be the closest you can get to a datasheet; you would probably need to figure the rest out by experimenting with it.

Comment: Sorry, but this is far from the full document :( Looks like these guys selling the documents and put this pages as a teaser.

Comment: I found more pieces of documents for the DDA 120 using google, but they all seem to be pieces of a larger document.  It seems that LeCroy created PDFs for the individual chapters.  I couldn't find any place with all of the chapters together.